# htaccess with multiple site codeigniter script

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

Hi everyone i am making multiple sites script using codeigniter,
1- I used htaccess to remove index.php
2- I making multiple sites working on same files so i want to pass the site name in a GET param so i want a htaccess code to make this

- `http://site_url.com/index.php/controller?site=username`

to be linke this

- `http://site_url.com/username/controller`

This is the basic code i am using to remove the index.php so my problem is with the site param.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php/$2?site=$1 [L,E]
```

Comment: i get 404 error when I enter http://site_url.com/username/ , also when i enter http://site_url.com/username/controller I get (Unable to load your default controller. Please make sure the controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid.) but when I enter  http://site_url.com/controller/controller i get my controller index function but with no params into the $_GET , any ideas ?

Comment: because username and controller_name are both required, and you need to change the uri_protocol to PATH_INFO in your config.php, $config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';

Comment: and you can set the default controller in your config/routes.php file => $route['default_controller'] = "controller/index";

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/main index.php/main?site=$1 [L]
```

I'm just a "noob" when it comes for htaccess, but this is how i would try